# Java Head First exercise

Tags: java, polymorphism

I've got a problem with exercise in Java Head First. Basically I don't understand why output changes based on  frighten's methode argument. I don't get what impact on output have values returned by classes Dragon, Vampire and Monster.

```
public class MonsterTestDrive {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Monster [] ma = new Monster[3];
        ma[0] = new Vampire();
        ma[1] = new Dragon();
        ma[2] = new Monster();
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
            ma[x].frighten(x);
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Monster {

// A

}
```

```
class Vampire extends Monster {

// B

}
```

```
class Dragon extends Monster {
    boolean frighten(int degree) {
        System.out.println(“breath fire”);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Which of the A-B pairs of methods listed on the right, if inserted into the classes on the left, would compile and produce the output shown?

(The A method inserted into class Monster, the B method inserted into class Vampire.)

```
 //1
boolean frighten(int d) {     
    System.out.println(“arrrgh”); //A
    return true;
}
boolean frighten(int x) {
    System.out.println(“a bite?”);//B
    return false;
}
```

```
//2
boolean frighten(int x) {
    System.out.println(“arrrgh”);//A
    return true;
}
int frighten(int f) {
    System.out.println(“a bite?”);//B
    return 1;
}
```

```
//3
boolean frighten(int x) {
    System.out.println(“arrrgh”); //A
    return false;
}
boolean scare(int x) {
    System.out.println(“a bite?”);//B
    return true;
}
```

```
//4
boolean frighten(int z) {
    System.out.println(“arrrgh”);//A
    return true;
}
boolean frighten(byte b) {
    System.out.println(“a bite?”);//B
    return true;
}
```

[Exercise img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbdut.jpg)

Comment: You may need to read some basic tutorial on method overriding [like this, part _Rules of method overriding_](https://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/method-overriding-in-java-with-example/).  The quiz question provides enough information about the signature of the methods that have to be provided in `Monster` and `Vampire` classes.  A brute force solution would be to copy the source code to some IDE and check the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is the answer.

Look at the method signature of *frighten* method in Dragon class. It takes integer as input and returns boolean as output.
So, the "frighten" of the parent class (**Monster**) must also have the same method signature.

```
boolean frighten(int d) {     
    System.out.println(“arrrgh”); //A
    return true;
}
```

Now, since the Vampire class is extending the Monster class and it is expected to override the *frighten* method, it should also have the same method signature and *same name*.

```
boolean frighten(int x) {
    System.out.println(“a bite?”);//B
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Okey, now i understand! Thank you for your help!